# shared clock vs. internal clock in react components

Tags: reactjs

I have a page with a lot of relative times (`updated 4 seconds ago`). I'm curious the best strategy to handle something like this. The first thought I had was to setup a context at the top level of my app that updates every second. Then all the `Time` components could consume that context and update on each tick. My worry here is if the top level provider is causing my app to re-render every second?

My second thought was to have the updater internal to the `Time` component, but then I have each `Time` component on the page running its own update cycle.

Any thoughts on what the most efficient way to handle this use case is?

Answer (score 0):

Most efficient way to do this will be to isolate the update within the components displaying the relative time. This will ensure that only this leaf component needs to be updated, rather than the entire component tree.

If you have a huge amount of such components, you will probably want to update them relatively infrequently to avoid using up too many resources on these updates.